# Passing the serialized data to the controller in MVC through AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a view :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/datatable/DataTables-1.10.20/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @section Scripts{

        <script src="~/Scripts/datatable/DataTables-1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/datatable/DataTables-1.10.20/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#contenttable").DataTable({

                });

                $("#submitdata").click(function () {
                    var datatabledata = $("#datatble-form").serialize();
                    alert(datatabledata);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/getData",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { model: datatabledata },
                        success: function () {
                            alert('success');
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('failure');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    }
</head>

<body>
    <form id="datatble-form">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Friend Name</td>
                <td><input name="FriendName" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Friend Age</td>
                <td><input name="FriendAge" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Position</td>
                <td><input name="Friendposition" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Office</td>
                <td><input name="Friendoffice" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input id="submitdata" type="button" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My controller is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using datatableViewTocontroller.Models;

namespace datatableViewTocontroller.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult getData(string model)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            MyClass myClass = jss.Deserialize<MyClass>(model);
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }

}
```

}

and My Model is :

```
namespace datatableViewTocontroller.Models
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string FriendName { get; set; }
        public string FriendAge { get; set; }
        public string Friendposition { get; set; }
        public string Friendoffice { get; set; }  
    }
}
```

Ok now I ellaborate my problem.
I have a form with the inputs for name, age, position and office and Iam trying to submit the data to the controller by serialize(). The form is getting serialized ( because it is displaying the values in the alert ) and controller call is also successfull like :

[image: You can see that controller parameters are getting received]

but while deserialzing I have got this error :
Invalid JSON primitive: FriendName.
like this :
[image: Error while Deserializing the values into the model]

How can I resolve this issue ? please help..

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are getting in your action method of controller is not json data that's why you are getting the error while deserializing it.

**Solution**

You can update your `getdata` method instead of passing string in parameter you can pass your model class which will bind data automatically and you will no longer required deserializing the json.

```js
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult getData(MyClass model)
{
  // Do whatever you want with model
  return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

And also change your click method as below

```js
$("#submitdata").click(function () {
 $.post("/Home/getData",$("#datatble-form").serialize()).done(function(data){
   alert('success');
 }).catch(function(){
  alert('failure');
 });
});
```

Comment: I tried what you have suggested but it is getting null value for the the model parameter.

Comment: @ajinkya I have updated code , Please check it now if it is working

Answer (score 0):

**1.Add `serializeObject` function to serialize `form data` to `json`**

```
<script>    
        (function ($) {
            $.fn.serializeObject = function () {

                var self = this,
                    json = {},
                    push_counters = {},
                    patterns = {
                        "validate": /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?:\[(?:\d*|[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\])*$/,
                        "key": /[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|(?=\[\])/g,
                        "push": /^$/,
                        "fixed": /^\d+$/,
                        "named": /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/
                    };


                this.build = function (base, key, value) {
                    base[key] = value;
                    return base;
                };

                this.push_counter = function (key) {
                    if (push_counters[key] === undefined) {
                        push_counters[key] = 0;
                    }
                    return push_counters[key]++;
                };

                $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function () {

                    // Skip invalid keys
                    if (!patterns.validate.test(this.name)) {
                        return;
                    }

                    var k,
                        keys = this.name.match(patterns.key),
                        merge = this.value,
                        reverse_key = this.name;

                    while ((k = keys.pop()) !== undefined) {

                        // Adjust reverse_key
                        reverse_key = reverse_key.replace(new RegExp("\\[" + k + "\\]$"), '');

                        // Push
                        if (k.match(patterns.push)) {
                            merge = self.build([], self.push_counter(reverse_key), merge);
                        }

                        // Fixed
                        else if (k.match(patterns.fixed)) {
                            merge = self.build([], k, merge);
                        }

                        // Named
                        else if (k.match(patterns.named)) {
                            merge = self.build({}, k, merge);
                        }
                    }

                    json = $.extend(true, json, merge);
                });

                return json;
            };
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#contenttable").DataTable({

                });

                $("#submitdata").click(function () {

                    var datatabledata = $("#datatble-form").serializeObject();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/getData",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { model: datatabledata },
                        crossDomain: true,
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.success == true) {
                                window.location = result.redirecturl;
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('failure');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

**2. No need to deserialize MyClass in action codes,**

```
public IActionResult Index(MyClass model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult getData(MyClass model)
        {
            //no need to deserialize MyClass
            return Json(new { success = true, redirecturl = Url.Action("Index", "Home", model) });
        }
```

Screenshots of test:
[image]